# GitHub webooks and custom payload

Tags: github, webhooks, git-webhooks

I'm looking at adding a couple of other name/value pairs in the json payload that is sent when a webhook detects an event. Is there a way to add in a value to the payload that is sent?

{
"ref": "release123",
"ref_type": "branch",
"master_branch": "develop",
"description": null,
"todaysdate": "Thursday",
"MyName": "John Smith",

something like the last 2??

Answer (score 1):

GitHub doesn't offer the ability to customize or filter webhook payloads.  If you need a different behavior from the webhook payload, it's up to your application to either select the items you want, generate the missing data (e.g., with an API call), or otherwise manipulate it so it meets your needs.